# how to reduceByKey on a transformation of the key and return the whole record

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, reduce

I have an RDD with `[String, Int]` type columns, respectively.

RDD values are like :

```
("A x",3)
("A y",4)
("A z",1)
("B y",2)
("C w",5)
("C y",2)
("E x",1)
("E z",3)
```

What I want to accomplish is to get an RDD like this `(String,Int)`:

```
("A y",4) #among the key's that contains y, (A y) has the max value
("A x",3) #among the key's that contains x, (A x) has the max value
("E z",3) #among the key's that contains z, (E z) has the max value
("C w",5) #among the key's that contains w, (C w) has the max value
```

I tried a loop concept (by using a counter) in `flatMap` but it doesn't work. 
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I think you want `myrdd.reduceByKey(max)`

Comment: @pault No, because if I use rdd.reduceByKey(max) as result we will get both « A x » and « E x » because as keys are uniques.

Comment: I see what you're saying and I've voted to reopen this question. I think the following will get what you want (assuming your inputs are clean): `rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0].split()[1], (x[0], x[1]))).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: max(a, b, key=lambda x: x[1])).map(lambda x: x[1])`. Ping me if the question gets reopened and I'll post an answer with a full explanation.

Comment: @user3483203 turns out that this not a dupe as I initially thought